# Ionization of Electrons Intensity Relationship

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, ionization-energy

Why can't light eject electrons out of atoms (ie. do ionization radiation)? Although the energy of light photons are low (more or less 2 eV), can't 5 photons consecutively hit the electron and make it go out of orbit?

Comment: Actually in some cases it can happen, although not very probably. In particular, multiphoton interactions are examples. I don't have a conclusive answer to your question, but hope other people could comment on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they can't. The energy an electron needs to be kicked out of its state needs to come in a single chunck, since the energy levels in an atom are quantized. Because for an electron of bound energy $E$ there is almost never a state with $E + 2\mathrm{eV}$, the atoms are unable to absorb visible light.

Well, they may be able to absorb visible light on specific wavelengths, but the transitions you hit with that will not be transitions into a free electron, just into some higher orbital. Yet, these states are very short-lived (the electron will fall back to the ground state quite fast by emitting a photon again) and in order to free the electron you would have to hit that excited state again with just the right frequency during its lifetime, and again, and again. The probability for this happening is so small that it is practically non-existent.

Comment: What if you shine a bright white light onto atoms? Different wavelenghts are present, different energy jumps possible.

Comment: @user154734: I realize my answer was a bit too quick. I will amend it.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know the coming back of the electron was that quick. I thought light (travelling much faster) could knock it off successively. Is there any reason behind why the electron can come back to it's initial state that fast?

Comment: @user154734: Nothing holds it there, and since time evolution drives systems always towards lower energies, it falls back "as fast as it can", i.e. it only stays there as long as it needs to re-emit the photon (I am afraid I know of no calculation that gives a result for exactly how long that time is, but empirically you find its really short - about $10^{-8}\mathrm{s} I think).

Comment: You seem highly knowleadgeable :) What is your field of study?

Comment: @user154734: Thanks for the compliment, though I must point out that comments that contribute nothing to the subject matter are discouraged here. As you could also see on my userpage, I am a student of physics with a theoretical inclination. If my answer satisfies you, click on the check mark below the upvote/downvote buttons on it so that your question is marked as answered. However, you are under no obligation to do so, it is fine if you choose to wait and see if someone with a better answer comes along.